# three.js gif image loader on before model load

Tags: three.js

How to show a gif image loader to indicate the status of the model on before load the 3d models using `OBJMTLLoader` or`AssimpJSONLoader` ? am using three.js version 67 and am using below code load the gif loader, but the function doesn't have any effect while load the model

```
var loadManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    loadManager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
        alert('hi');
        console.log( item, loaded, total );
    };

 var objloader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader(loadManager);
```

what am doing wrong here, am missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick read of the [LoadingManager docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/LoadingManager) it seems that the class does not show progress of a single loader, but it shows the progress of many.
So if you send the loading manager 4 loaders, the onProgress event would fire 4 times with the 'loaded' variable being 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: ? Is it working? The LoadingManager class works as it should. It is not designed to show progress of individual files.

Comment: Not working, it doesn't call while we attach it with the loader

Comment: That is what I am saying. It does not work the way you seem to be expecting. It does not show progress of individual files, it shows the progress of a group of multiple files. I am not sure how I can explain this any clearer.

Comment: ok, i got it, `LoadingManager` is not works with the `OBJMTLLoader`, it is working with `AssimpJSONLoader`